# Forge API changes

Tags: autodesk-forge

This question is aimed at Autodesk Forge folks who participate in this forum.

When changes are made to the Forge API, or how it interacts with BIM 360, where are the detailed release notes?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [Change History](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/change_history/document_management_v1_changelog/) for BIM 360, which contains detailed information about API changes. For more generic information, [check our blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/autodesk-products/bim-360).

Comment: Thank you Augusto.  However, BIM 360 API and Forge API has changed several times since the last noted change history of 2020-03-27.  Example:  Permissioning access to Doc Mgmt was modified sometime near June 15.  I assume your release is probably monthly?

Comment: David,  Could you tell us what you find has changed?  We will double check with the product team.  But as a general rule, officially released API should not make any breaking changes without versioning.  (In this case, it's beta. So it may get a little tricky.  But at least we should notify.)